# Not sure if cron job is run

Tags: bash, shell-script, cron

I have the following cron job in `/etc/cron.d/backup`:

```
*/1 * * * * backupbot /home/backupbot/bin/backup-script.sh
```

Basically, I want the `backup-script.sh` to run every minute (and the user *backupbot* should be executing the job).

The `/home/backupbot/bin/backup-script.sh` file is owned by *backupbot* (and he has "x" permission on it). The file looks as follows:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
set -e

{

BACKUP_DIR=/var/app/backups
STORAGE_ACCOUNT_URL=https://myserver/backups

BACKUP_FILE=$(ls $BACKUP_DIR -t | head -1)

if [ -z "$BACKUP_FILE" ]; then
    echo "There are no backups to synchronize"
    exit 0
fi

azcopy login --identity
azcopy copy $BACKUP_DIR/$BACKUP_FILE $STORAGE_ACCOUNT_URL/$BACKUP_FILE

} >/tmp/cron.backup-script.$$ 2>&1
```

Normally, any output should be logged into `/tmp/cron.backup-script.xxxx`. Such a file is never created.

The only evidence that the job is being noticed by Cron is the following output of `systemctl status cron.service`:

```
● cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2021-04-13 09:59:08 UTC; 6h ago
     Docs: man:cron(8)
 Main PID: 1086 (cron)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
           └─1086 /usr/sbin/cron -f

Apr 13 16:00:01 my-vm CRON[17201]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Apr 13 16:00:01 my-vm CRON[17198]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Apr 13 16:00:01 my-vm CRON[17199]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Apr 13 16:01:01 my-vm CRON[17402]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Apr 13 16:01:01 my-vm CRON[17403]: (root) CMD ([ -f /etc/krb5.keytab ] && [ \( ! -f /etc/opt/omi/creds/omi.keytab \) -o \( /etc/krb5.keytab -nt /etc/opt/omi/creds/omi.keytab \) ] &&
Apr 13 16:01:01 my-vm CRON[17401]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user backupbot by (uid=0)
Apr 13 16:01:01 my-vm CRON[17404]: (backupbot) CMD (/home/backupbot/bin/backup-script.sh)
Apr 13 16:01:01 my-vm CRON[17402]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Apr 13 16:01:01 my-vm CRON[17401]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Apr 13 16:01:01 my-vm CRON[17401]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user backupbot
```

It mentions something about sessions for *backupbot*. How can I investigate further?

Comment: One additional thing that is weird: when I run this script (backup-script.sh) on my local computer, where the `/var/app/backups` directory doesn't exist, I get the following log: `ls: cannot access '/var/app/backups': No such file or directory
There are no backups to synchronize`. Shouldn't the script exit on the `ls` error already? I have the `set -e`...

Comment: The subshell that runs `ls` does not have `set -e` enabled, and if it had, exiting the subshell would not terminate the script.  The exit status of the command substitution is the exit status of `head`, and that runs successfully.

Comment: Since you say that the output file isn't created, it means that the script never executes to the `{ ...; }`.  I.e., it never even starts (or terminates straight after `set -e`, which is terribly unlikely).  Could you show the permissions and ownership of the file `/home/backupbot/bin/backup-script.sh`?

Comment: @Kusalananda Here's the metadata about `/home/backupbot/bin/backup-script.sh`: `---x------ 1 backupbot marcin         428 Apr 13 15:45 backup-script.sh*`

Comment: So, you can't actually _read_ the script.  Does it work if you make it readable by the owner?

Comment: Oh, I wouldn't think about it. I changed the permissions to "500". And I see the log in `/tmp`! Thanks! I wonder, isn't there any bultin logging mechanism that would tell me that corn can't even run the script?

Comment: Normally, the cron daemon would send an email message to the owner of the job if the job produced errors or any other output. If you haven't set up local delivery of mail on your system, such emails would be discarded. I don't know how this is normally organized on Linux (I'm not a Linux user).

Comment: `(CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)` -- having a working email system, even within the same host would help a lot in debugging cron, as you'd get any errors in the emails. What options there are to do that easily (and without exposing the SMTP server to the internet...) may depend on the distribution, though. Anyway, lacking that, an alternative would be to put redirections directly the crontab command, i.e. `*/1 * * * * backupbot /home/backupbot/bin/backup-script.sh > /tmp/crontest.out 2>/tmp/crontest.error`, or `> file 2>&1` to put both in the same file, or something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/644907/not-sure-if-cron-job-is-run?noredirect=1#comment1208286_644907), the script is *only* executable by the owner.  I.e., it is not readable.  This stops the owner from executing the script.

Example:

```
$ chmod 500 script
$ ls -l script
-r-x------ 1 myself myself 24 Apr 14 09:21 script
$ ./script
hello
```

```
$ chmod 100 script
$ ls -l script
---x------ 1 myself myself 24 Apr 14 09:21 script
$ ./script
/bin/bash: ./script: Permission denied
```

If the script file is not readable, it can't be read by the `bash` shell interpreter (which is running as the current user).

Make the script both executable and readable.

---

Apart from the above, consider using [proper double quoting of variable expansions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766), and [don't parse the output from `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985) (it's only really useful to *look at*).

Your script, modified:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

backup_dir=/var/app/backups
storage_account_url=https://myserver/backups

{
    # Find most recently modified file in "$backup_dir".
    # Assumes that there are only files there, no subdirectories.

    set -- "$backup_dir"/*
    backup_file_path=$1
    shift

    for pathname do
        if [ "$pathname" -nt "$backup_file_path" ]; then
            backup_file_path=$pathname
        fi
    done
    
    if [ ! -e "$backup_file_path" ]; then
        echo 'There are no backups to synchronize'
        exit 1
    fi
    
    # Perform backup.

    azcopy login --identity || exit 1
    azcopy copy "$backup_file_path" "$storage_account_url/$(basename "$backup_file_path")"

} >/tmp/cron.backup-script.$$ 2>&1
```

Comment: Great advices. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Jobs run through `cron`, or `at`, or `batch`, aren't run in the same runtime environment that you have on your desktop. None of your `PATH` changes, or other environment  variable settings are automatically propagated to  your `cron` job. For example, there's no `$DISPLAY`, so GUI programs need special treatment (read `man xhost`).

One can set environment variables for all one's `cron` jobs in the `crontab` file
Read `man 5 crontab`.

Look at the results of  `echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments.

Since the `command` part of the `crontab` line is, by default,  interpreted by `/bin/sh`, which has a simpler syntax than `/bin/bash`, I recommend having `command` be a call to a `bash` script  (executable, mounted, starts with `#!/bin/bash`) which sets up the environment,  then calls the desired program.

Always use absolute paths (paths starting at `/`, the root directory) in scripts run through `cron`, `at`, `batch`.

Comment: The script that I run through `cron` already starts with `#!/bin/bash`. Even if some command is unrecognized, all is inside of `{}`, and it is redirected to a file (with absolute path - `/tmp/cron.backup-script.$$`). So I suppose that any problem would be logged into this file, right? But it's not..